# How to fix: Failed to load API definition?

Tags: magento2

I have this problem when i check API with swagger. Can somebody tell me why cause this issue and how can i fix this issue:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is means that you have incorrect API Schema by request `/rest/all/schema?services=all`.

Some 3rd party extension or your custom code cause the error.

For debug I recommend to switch environment into developer mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

and see response of `/rest/all/schema?services=all`

Comment: Thank for your help, i really want to upvote this answer but i do not have enough reputation